# Can't enable application after deployment in wildfly 9.0.2 console

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I use wildfly 9.0.2.Final and want to deploy an application by console like in the picture below:

[image]

After I add `MyApp.war` I click on `view -> Enable -> Confirm`. It gives the following error. What am I doing wrong?

> unable to modify deployment.

Comment: Are there any messages in the log?

Comment: ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MyApp.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"MyApp.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED"}}

Comment: That looks like something is wrong with your WAR. Try executing `jar tf MyApp.war` to see the structure of it.